# DataTables deferred loading with columns option

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I'm using server-side processing mode (`"serverSide": true`) of jQuery DataTables. I'm using the [deferred loading option](https://datatables.net/reference/option/deferLoading) to optimize my page load times.

I'm also using the `columns` option, but there is some conflict when I define the `columns` option myself. It tries to look for the data source when there isn't any for the first call, which is the whole point of deferred loading.

> Uncaught Error: DataTables warning: table id=table - Requested unknown parameter 'id' for row 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

Initialization code:

```
function initialize_table(inital_length)
{
    table_options = {
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": '/merchant/all/',
            "type": 'POST',
            "deferRender": true,
            // data: JSON.stringify(data),
            // contentType: "application/json",
        },
        // "order": [[0, 'asc']]
        "deferRender": true,
        "processing": true,
        "pageLength": 50,
        "deferLoading": inital_length,
        "lengthMenu": [ 20, 50, 100, 200, 500 ],
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                // "class": "details-control",
                'data': 'gr_id', // response[data]
                'name': 'gr_id', 
                'orderable': true,
                'search': {'regex': false, 'value': ''},
                'searchable': true,
                "targets": 0,
            },
            { 
                'data': "name",
                'name': 'name',
                'orderable': true,
                'search': {'regex': false, 'value': ''},
                'searchable': true,
                "targets": 1,

            },
            { 
                'data': "address",
                'name': 'address',
                'orderable': false,
                'search': {'regex': false, 'value': ''},
                'searchable': true,
                "targets": 2,
            },
            {
                'data': "category",
                'name': 'category',
                'orderable': true,
                'search': {'regex': false, 'value': ''},
                'searchable': true,
                "targets": 3,
            },
            {
                'data': "chain",
                'name': 'chain',
                'orderable': true,
                'search': {'regex': false, 'value': ''},
                'searchable': true,
                "targets": 4,
            },
            {
                'data': "enabled",
                'name': 'enabled',
                'orderable': true,
                'search': {'regex': false, 'value': ''},
                'searchable': true,
                "targets": 5,
            },
            {
                'data': 'status',
                'name': 'status',
                'orderable': true,
                'search': {'regex': false, 'value': ''},
                'searchable': true,
                "targets": 6,
            }
        ],
    }
    var merchant_table = $("#merchant-table").DataTable(table_options);
}
```

Comment: This error usually means that the data format is incorrect, see more [here](http://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4#Parameter-is-a-string). If you have `deferLoading` set to positive number along with `serverSide: true`, it should not request data on the first call, there may be other errors that cause this. Please show your DataTables initialization code and data returned by the server.

Comment: No errors thrown when I don't define `columns`, or `columnDefs` (Then it uses it's default, refers to columns by it's indices.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bug of using `deferLoading` option together with `column.data` was [once reported](https://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/20693/bug-with-server-side-processing-deferloading-and-columns-definition) in DataTables forums. I was able to reproduce that bug using [v1.10.2 from CDN](http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/), but not using v1.10.3 onwards, so we can say that this has been fixed. This was probably fixed by the [new feature](http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.3/#New) "*Ability to use columns.data with a DOM sourced data to read the row information into an object rather than an array*".

So you can:

1) First make sure you are using the [latest version](http://datatables.net/download/index).

2) Check your JSON response. According to your comments, you're using an [array data source type](https://www.datatables.net/manual/data#Arrays), but when you set the [`column.data`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data) option, you must use [object data source type](https://www.datatables.net/manual/data#Objects) instead.

Comment: Using the latest version. Getting the error on page load - When it's not even making an ajax request - hence getting no JSON response, the first time the page is loaded, the server renders the html. Also, haven't what I used object data source type ? It's an array of objects, just like in the documentation ?

Comment: well the mistake does ultimately lie with my `"columns"` definition since on removing it, it works as intended (when it uses it's default)

Comment: Well, the newer version fixed the problem